# Ambassador helm chart upgrade fails with resource already exists in the cluster and wasn't defined in the previous release error

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager, ambassador

Updating ambassador helm chart with

`helm upgrade --install --wait ambassador -f ambassador-helm-values.yaml stable/ambassador`

fails with:

```sh
UPGRADE FAILED
Error: kind ClusterRoleBinding with the name "ambassador-crds" already exists in the cluster and wasn't defined in the previous release. Before upgrading, please either delete the resource from the cluster or remove it from the chart
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: kind ClusterRoleBinding with the name "ambassador-crds" already exists in the cluster and wasn't defined in the previous release. Before upgrading, please either delete the resource from the cluster or remove it from the chart
```

Deleted ClusterRoleBinding `ambassador-crds` and tried to run `helm upgrade` command. Which generates the `ambassador-crds` again and fails with same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install the specific resource via kubectl first? For generating the yamls you could use dry-run in debug mode. For example:

```
helm install . --dry-run --debug --generate-name
```

This should output the generated resources on your screen. Then copy the crd which wasnt defined in the previous release into a separate yaml-file (i.e. customResourceDefinition.yaml) and install it manually by using kubectl:

```
kubectl apply -f ./customResourceDefinition.yaml
```

After that you could try the `helm upgrade` command again.
Maybe the upgrade command is really strict and every resource has to exist before any action is taken.

This is only a workaround and a guess. I havent had this problem before and didnt used the `helm upgrade` at all. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using helm version `2.15.*`. This seems to be a bug on helm (or Tiller). The option `--cleanun-on-fail` does not seem to work either. I use to delete the resource that's complaining about and run the helm upgrade again but I find it annoying having to do this repeatedly. What works for me is adding the option `--atomic`. If provided, the upgrade process rolls back changes made in case of failed upgrade.

The seems to be an issue with Tiller(server-side db) getting corrupted. See discussion here in github: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6031